# Correct PDO Syntax for Updating an Array of primary keys.

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, pdo, prepared-statement

Hi_I’m trying to run a PDO Update on my database whenever a certain event in my Facebook Canvas game occurs, but I’ve run into some difficulty with my syntax, I hope someone here can help.

I have a table named `Balance`. This table contains the following columns: `facebookID`, `goldbalance` and `invite`. 
This table stores each player’s gold balance, and the `invite` column records whether or not the player has sent a successful (accepted) game invite to another player.

What I’m currently doing is this: When a new player joins the game, I run a check on Facebook’s Graph API to see which (if any) other players invited this new player, if they have, then I grab their IDs and then do an AJAX post to send them to a PHP file where I want to reward the `goldbalance` of these players by +100 gold, I also want to change their `invite` column from `0` to `1` (this will cause a pop-up to display, informing them of the reward the next time they log into the game).

Right now I’m successfully sending the IDs of the invite senders to my PHP file as an Array, however I haven’t been able to successfully do the PDO Update on the players’ gold balances.

This is my AJAX code which sends the IDs in an Array:

```
// requestid is the Array containing the sender IDs
   $.ajax({
    url: 'scripts/requestreward.php',
    data: {'requestid' : requestid},
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response){

        alert(response);
                }
   });
```

And this is my current PDO PHP file:

```
<?php

$servername = myservername;
$username = myusername;
$password = mypassword;
$dbname = mydbname;

//Create connection:
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `Balance` 
SET `goldbalance` = `goldbalance` + 100,
`invite` = 1,
WHERE `facebookID` = :requestId,

foreach($_POST['requestid'] as $requestId){
`facebookID`="($requestId)"; }");

$stmt->bindParam(':requestid', $requestid);
$requestid = $_POST['requestid'];
$stmt->execute();

$conn->commit();
echo "Success";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

I've been trying to do this as a prepared PDO statement because I've read that that's more secure, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing the update loop for each item in the array incorrectly.

Also, I'm not sure if this line is the correct way to increase the player's gold balance (which is an INT) by 100: `` SET `goldbalance` = `goldbalance` + 100, ``

Any help at all with this would be really appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: that code is just flat out wrong. your SQL is unterminated with a dangling `,` and a missing `");`, and would STILL be vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is not valid PHP syntax. You can't just make a `foreach` in a string.

Write your statement with your placeholder, then iterate over all your `requestId` to execute statement as many times as needed.

Take a look at this code, it should work as you want.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `Balance` 
    SET `goldbalance` = `goldbalance` + 100,
    `invite` = 1
    WHERE `facebookID` = :requestId");

    $stmt->bindParam(':requestId', $requestId);

    foreach($_POST['requestid'] as $r) { 
        $requestId = $r;
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    echo "Success";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Moreover, your `$con->commit()` is useless as you didn't start a transaction.

**Note about security**

As Marc B say it on comments, your code **is vulnerable to SQL injections**. You should take a look at how to clean up data from user input before using it on your query.

Comment: The bindParam should be outside the foreach (since it is bound as a reference and not as a value, there is no need to bind it more than once): `$stmt->bindParam(':requestid', $requestId); foreach($_POST['requestid'] as $requestId) { $stmt->execute(); }`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I'm used to use `bindValue()`. I corrected it.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Blackus thanks for your reply! I'm trying your code but it's giving me this error message: ``Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `facebookID` = '107263943372127'' at line 4`` do you know what might be wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi again @Mr.Blackus it turned out the comma at the end of `` invite` = 1,`` was causing the error, everything's working perfectly now, thanks again! I was wondering, on the security side of things, is this code still vunerable to SQL injections? As the data being passed to it (the IDs) comes directly from Facebook's API, is there still a risk of an injection attack?

Comment: Oups, missed that, I corrected. Hum, in fact, as you are using `bindParam()`, you should be protected from SQL injections. Speak too fast. But you should check what's on your `$_POST` variable before using it. At least for the format. It's supposed to be an array, but you never check that. Not a security issue, but your code will raise a warning if it's something else.